# Firebase Storage and Android images

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

So I want to basically get an image from Firebase storage (I have rules set to public).

This is what I have

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Glide.with(this)
    .load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-7c916.appspot.com/o/images.jpg?alt=media&token=b207cb11-9ad5-48e3-86ac-1dcb07ee6013")
    .into(image);
```

And I instead of using an https link. I want to use a storage reference. But everytime I try to use a storage reference my app crashes.
Please help.

Like the .child()   method.

Comment: Can you please provide error log where your app getting crash. So it will helps us to figure crash more quickly.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [`StorageReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/create-reference) to load Firebase storage image.

```
   // Reference to an image file in Cloud Storage
StorageReference storageReference = = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("myimage");


ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

// Load the image using Glide
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(image );
```

For more details You can check [Using FirebaseUI to download and display images](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/README.md).

Comment: While using a `StorageReference` from the Firebase SDK is indeed one way to download from Cloud Storage, there is also a publicly readable, unguessable download URL. That's what Alexei is using here, so it should work with any library that can download from HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you sir for more info about to access Firebase storage. So for Alexei case, we need to figure out why app getting crash.

Comment: When I try this FirebaseImageLoader does not show up in blue? I cannot use it? My app is xamarin.android only

Comment: @pRaNaY Could you tell me which version and what type of `Glide` library should I use? Now I have tried *`glide-full-4.6.1.jar`* and *`glide-full-4.5.0.jar`*, but there isn't such a method `using()` and class `FirebaseImageLoader()`...

Answer (score 1):

Put this class [FirebaseImageLoader.java](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/storage/images/FirebaseImageLoader.java) into your source, or write yourself.

Make a class anywhere in your app source like below.

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

@Override
public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
    // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
    registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
            new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

Where you want to load image coad like below.

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage
                                    .getInstance().getReference().child("myimage");

Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
      .load(completeStorageRefranceToImage)
      .into(imageView);
```

[Please refer for more details.](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/README.md)

Comment: Small note: Also clean project, then do build. After that all should work.

Answer (score 0):

So used pRaNaY's code like this

```
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images.jpg");
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Glide.with(this).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storageReference).into(image );
```

There reason I want to use a reference is because I will have names of all the images in a txt file and I will read the names of images from it and create a while loop to load all the images I need into the right place.

Just one more question, How do i know if the image is null without checking if the ImageView is null?